# Creating a Pop up and setting its view state before it displays

Tags: apache-flex, popup, viewstate, initialization

I am a beginner developer in Flex, and I have been using viewstates lately. I had a couple of custom popup titlewindow components that are initialized using:

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, ContentCreate, true);
```

They both contain view states already, and are very similar so I wanted to combione them into one popup titlewindow and change view state on initialisation of the popup to either the Create version of the popup or the Update.

I thought I was being smart haha, but I realized soon after refactoring my code that, I as far as I know I can't pass parameters to the popup to indicate which state I want, if it is created using the PopUpManager.

Does anyone know how to pass parameters to the PopupManager, or create the ContentCreate component(TitleWindow) in mxml or code so I can specify the view state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a pop up window using the createPopUp method a reference to the created window is returned.
Example:

```
pop = mx.managers.PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, TitleWindow, false);
```

You can create a public setState function to tell the new popup window which state to display.

```
pop = mx.managers.PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, TitleWindow, false);
pop.setDisplay('Update');
```

Your example would be more like:

```
var pop:ContentCreate;
pop = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, ContentCreate, true) as ContentCreate;
pop.setState('Update');
```

This should work.

More information can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#centerPopUp()).

Hope this helps.